# running LinearRegression model using scikit-learn with different pandas dataframe (loop question)

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with cost, wind, solar and hour of day and like to use the linear regression model from scikit-learn to find the how wind and solar impact the cost. I have labelled each hour with P1-P24 (24 hour a day) i.e. each row depending on the hour of the day will be assigned with a P(1-24)

Therefore i have defined each corresponding row of wind/solar/cost to different dataframe according to the hour of the day

The code runs okay with everything i wanted to do. However I struggle to build a for loop code run repeatedly for every hour to find the linreg.intercept, linreg.coef and np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred) function from scikit-learn on various panda dataframe (P1 to P24).

So at the moment i have to manually change the P number 24 times to find the corresponding intercept/coefficient/mean squared error for each hour

I have some code below for the work but i always struggle to build for loop

I tried to build the for loop using for i in [P1,P2...] but the dataframe became a list and i also struggle to incorporate it to the scikit-learn part

b is the original dataframe with columns: cost, Period (half hourly, therefore i have period 1 to 48), wind, solar

import dataframe

```
 b = pd.read_csv('/Users/Downloads/cost_latest.csv')
```

To put it into hourly therefore:

```
 P1 = b[b['Period'].isin(['01','02'])]
 P2 = b[b['Period'].isin(['03','04'])]...
```

the scikit-learn part:

```
 feature_cols = ['wind','Solar']
 X = P1[feature_cols]
 y = P1['Price']
```

and here is my issue, i need to change the P1 to P2...P24 before running the following codes to get my parameters

the following are the scikit-learn part:

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

 linreg = LinearRegression()
```

fit the model to the training data (learn the coefficients)

```
 linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
 print(linreg.intercept_)
 print(linreg.coef_)
 list(zip(feature_cols, linreg.coef_))
 y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
 from sklearn import metrics
 print(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

I think there is a smarter way to avoid me manually editing the following (P value) and running everything in one go, i welcome your advice, suggestions
thanks

```
 X = P1[feature_cols]
 y = P1['Price']
```

Comment: So you want to create and train a separate model for every (half) hour?

Comment: I would like to see if there is a smart way to edit the codes above to test every P value i.e. P1 to P24 without having to manually the P number

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just use this:**

```
for P in [P1,P2, P3,P4,P5,P6,P7]:
    X = P[feature_cols]
    y = P['Price']
```

**All together:**

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

all_intercepts = []
all_coefs = []

for P in [P1,P2, P3,P4,P5,P6,P7]:
    X = P[feature_cols]
    y = P['Price']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(linreg.intercept_)
    print(linreg.coef_)
    list(zip(feature_cols, linreg.coef_))
    y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
    print(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
    all_intercepts.append(linreg.intercept_)
    all_coefs.append(linreg.coef_)


print(all_intercepts)
print(all_coefs)
```

`P` will be your dataframes P1,P2,... according to each iteration

Comment: thanks a lot!!! im getting a list of numbers now. It is fully readable but is there a way of putting it nicely in a dataframe? currently having the following i.e.  1.391965608695747
[0.00073866 0.        ]
2.607460037321706
1.7023870511763968
[0.00067533 0.        ]
2.8697282847868113

Comment: see my updated answer. use new lists to append the results

Answer (score 0):

Put all `Pn` dataframes in a list and run your code.

```
all_P  = [P1, P2, P3]

for P in all_P:
    X = P[feature_cols]
    y = P['Price']
```

Comment: `all_P ` is not needed. see my answer

Comment: I would recommend it though to increase readability---taking into account there are 24 of these.